# Intersection of lists from lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, intersection

Task is find number of equal elements in 2 lists,which are contain lists.
I have 2 lists which looks like

```
DNF1=[[4], [12], [20], [28,32], [36], [44], [52,54], [60,4],[60,24]]
DNF2=[[16], [20,60], [24], [28,32], [48], [52], [56,58], [60,4]]
```

This code does not work cause arguments are lists:

```
 count=sum(1 for k in DNF1 if k in DNF2)
```

How can I write

```
func(DNF1,DNF2)
```

which will return

```
[[28,32],[60,4]]
```

or just '2' (amount of elements in intersection)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
DNF1 = [[4], [12], [20], [28, 32], [36], [44], [52, 54], [60, 4], [60, 24]]
DNF2 = [[16], [20, 60], [24], [28, 32], [48], [52], [56, 58], [60, 4]]


intersection = set(map(tuple, DNF1)) & set(map(tuple, DNF2))
result = [list(e) for e in intersection]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[60, 4], [28, 32]]
```

The idea is to convert `DNF1` and `DNF2` to sets, but as list are not hashable you need to convert them to tuples. Once you have `DNF1` and `DNF2` as sets find the intersection and convert back to list each element in the intersection. The complexity of this approach is *O(n)*.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension:

```
[DNF1[i] for i in range(len(DNF1)) if len(DNF1[i]) > 1 and DNF1[i] in DNF2 ]

[[28, 32], [60, 4]]
```